# Continuous function agreeing at two points

Tags: calculus

> Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous non-negative function such that $f(0) = f(1)$. Show that for every $0<r<1$ there exists $x,y\in[0,1]$ such that $|x-y| = r$ and $f(x) = f(y)$.

Thanks for helpers!

Comment: Consider the function $g(x) := f(x+r) - f(x)$, $x\in [0, 1-r]$.

Comment: Isn't this false as written? Consider the piecewise-linear function with $f(0)=2$, $f(1/2-\epsilon)=3$, $f(1/2+\epsilon)=1$, $f(1)=2$. Then no two points more than $1/2+\epsilon$ apart can have the same value; the value will always be $\gt 2$ for $x\in(0, 1/2-\epsilon)$ and $\lt 2$ for $y\in(1/2+\epsilon,1)$, and any two points in the unit interval at distance greater than $1/2+\epsilon$ will have to fall one into each of these intervals.  You probably also need $f(0)=f(1)=0$ to prove the statement.

Answer (score 1):

You start from your continuous function $f\colon [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(0) = f(1)$. Thanks to this last condition, you can extend it to a $1$-periodic continuous function in $\mathbb{R}$.

Since $f$ is continuous, by Weierstrass' theorem there exist $x_0, x_1\in [0,1]$ such that
$$
(1)\qquad
f(x_0) = \min_{x\in [0,1]} f(x),
\qquad
f(x_1) = \max_{x\in [0,1]} f(x).
$$

Let us consider the continuous function
$$
g(x) := f(x+r) - f(x),
\qquad x\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
By (1) we have that
$$
g(x_0) = f(x_0+r) - f(x_0) \geq 0,
\qquad
g(x_1) = f(x_1+r) - f(x_1) \leq 0,
$$
hence there exists $c$ in the interval $[x_0, x_1]$ (or $[x_1, x_0]$ depending on the relative position of $x_0$ and $x_1$) such that $g(c) = 0$.
The conclusion now follows choosing $x = c$ and $y = c+r$.